# Table header disappear in same powershell session

Tags: powershell

I am using this code to show the status

```
Function Print
{param($name, $age)
  $obj = New-Object System.Object
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Name($name)
  $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Age($age)
  Write-Output $obj
}
```

The message print properly when i call this method for the first time. But when i call it again, only the data prints. How to make sure that header(NotePropertyname) shows every time?

Comment: PowerShell is trying to do you a favour since the data sets are the same. Why would you want to see the headers everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the headers everytime, use format commands.

```
Print($XX,$YY) | ft -auto
```

Comment: Understand that this will destroy the object so you will not be able to use the output again. Use this with caution. Also, If you were going to do that you might as well just add it into the function.